# Cannot insert into MySQL database using MySQLdb python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have been trying to insert into a MySQL database from python using the MySQLdb interface. While I have been able to successfully execute select queries, my insert queries do nothing. They return no errors, but also do not add anything to the database.

I simplified my program down to just this.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user=...,passwd=...,db=...)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO user_event_log (username, major_event_id, minor_event_id, value, date) VALUES ('Test', 1, 1, '0.1', '2017-07-29')""")
```

Not sure if I am making a really dumb mistake, but I can't figure out why nothing is inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit changes in database and close the database.
Please follow below changes of code:

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user=...,passwd=...,db=...)

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = """INSERT INTO user_event_log (username, major_event_id, minor_event_id, value, date) VALUES ('Test', 1, 1, '0.1', '2017-07-29')"""
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `MySQLdb.commit()` to your connection. ([Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html))

This is as simple as adding `db.commit()` to the end of your code.

Hope it helps!